# Google Tv Emulator AVD System Image

Tags: android, google-tv

Hi i am trying to set up google tv emulator in my windows machine.I am able to install googleTv Adon avilable in api level 13

But when i am trying to create AVD it throws a errormessage Please install intelx86.
But X86 System image is not avilable in api 13.
Can anyone help me please.

Comment: No, you haven't attached anything.

Comment: ya i am not able to attach but the error i get is To Create AVD Please install the x86 system image for Android(3.2)api first

Comment: To Create AVD Please install the x86 system image for Android(3.2)api first

Answer (score 4):

The solution is to create avd with a command line.

```
android create avd -n GoogleTV -t 11
```

Where 11 is the api id. In your system this will be different then mine so first issue  a comamnd

```
android list target
```

In my case it was

...
id: 11 or "Google Inc.:Google TV Addon:12"
Name: Google TV Addon
....

For convenience on linux you can use

```
android list target | grep TV -B 2
```

Comment: Hi marekdf,When i give android list targets i am not getting google tv adon itself i am just getting API 17 what would be the mistake can you tell me please

Comment: Well you have to download it. 
Run
 android sdk
and install Google APIs

Comment: I have installed and it is showing in my eclipse workspace when i am create avd but not showing in command prompt.

Comment: Perhaps you have to sdk(s) installed?
Do you have a folder name addon-google_tv_addon-google in you sdk?

In my case is 
/home/marekdef/android-sdk-linux/add-ons/addon-google_tv_addon-google-12

Answer (score 0):

Run `Android SDK Manager` and install the image it wants.

Comment: The Api (13) doesnt contain the image to install that is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the above but none of the them  are working for me , still getting the same error. this is happening o on my windows i5 machine.

Could someone tell me anyone is able to install the AVD for Google-TV on windows machine..

Answer (score 0):

1. Download Google TV Addon API-13
2. Download Android 2.3.3 Intel x86 atom system image.
3. Enter the path which Android SDK installed. Do these things follow:

   - Copy ..\sdk\system-images\android-10\x86  to  ..\sdk\system-images\android-13\x86
   - Modify the file sdk\system-images\android-13\x86\source.properties
         Pkg.Desc=Android SDK Platform 3.2
         Pkg.Revision=1
         AndroidVersion.ApiLevel=13
4. Restart AVD manager.
5. Create AVD follow Google TV document.

The emulator can power on.
But the performance is so poor. It always ANR and force close. I suggest you do not develop on it.