# This avd may not work unless you install the x86 system image for Android 3.2 (API 13)first

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, google-tv

I am using **Ubuntu 12.04** and trying to create **AVD for Google TV**, but getting:

```
 This avd may not work unless you install the x86 system image for Android 3.2 (API 13)first
```

using **Eclipse ADT**

Comment: go to android sdk manager .There you find intel system atom x 86 image install that package..

Comment: i already installed with android 4.4.2, but not found for android 3.2 or 3.1 in SDK Manager

Comment: there is Google TV addon install that also..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16905602/google-tv-emulator-avd-system-image see here

Comment: already installed google tv add on for both 3.2 and 3.1

Comment: I have the same problem, opened a bug report here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77898 please vote it up

Comment: https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/03/06/now-available-android-sdk-x86-system-image-with-google-apis  follow the link. it helped me resolving same issue. And if you face HAXM not working or not installed then folloew up this link https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-windows

Comment: @Sun that is not available for android 3.2 or earlier versions.